# How to print formatted contents of Computed Field in a custom template?

Tags: 7, theming, emails, entities

I am trying to edit a bit body of simplenews newsletter that's being sent.
I have a computed field that captures ~50 first words and saves it.
It is called : `field_first_sentance` and it's value is being saved in :

`$entity->field_first_sentence['und'][0]['value']` .

In `sites/all/modules/contrib/simplenews/simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php` I added :

```
<?php print_r($entity->field_first_sentence['und'][0]['value']); ?>
```

I have tried with both `echo` and `print` and with `l(strip_html(t($entity->field_first_sentence['und'][0]['value'])))` and I've received same error.

But when I try to send a test newsletter I get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzRgU.jpg) , which is basically saying that I can't have `$entity` in that file(simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php).

Is there a way to go around this and make it work ?

Thanks,
Michael!